# How to return an array in Java method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I would like to create a method that returns a string array. I tried this code but it has problems with returning `T_NazwaJadlospisu` array.

```java
public static String[] listJadlospis() {
    try {
        state = con.createStatement();
        result = state.executeQuery("SELECT NazwaJadlospisu FROM Jadlospis GROUP BY NazwaJadlospisu");
        while (result.next()) {
            Array z = result.getArray("NazwaJadlospisu");
            String[] T_NazwaJadlospisu = (String[]) z.getArray();

            // String T_NazwaJadlospisu =
            // result.getString("NazwaJadlospisu");
            // System.out.println("Jadłospis: " + T_NazwaJadlospisu);
        }
        return T_NazwaJadlospisu;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Query error.");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.err.println("Element not found.");
    }
}
```

SQL returns as follows:

```sql
mysql> SELECT NazwaJadlospisu FROM Jadlospis GROUP BY NazwaJadlospisu;
+-----------------+
| NazwaJadlospisu |
+-----------------+
| dieta 1500 kcal |
| dieta testowa1  |
| test1           |
+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any hints on what I do wrong and what would be the best way to return SELECT SQL statement output from a method. Thanks in advance for helping.

---

OK, I have followed most of yours pointers and went a bit further. Now I got an error message like this:
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException

In general, what I would like to do is to have a method listJadlospis returning a String array with all 3 rows from NazwaJadlospisu column.

Now, the source looks like this:

```
public static String[] listJadlospis(){
    String[] nazwajadlospisu = null;
    try{
        state = con.createStatement();
        result = state.executeQuery("SELECT NazwaJadlospisu FROM Jadlospis GROUP BY NazwaJadlospisu");
        while(result.next()){
            Array z = result.getArray("NazwaJadlospisu");
            nazwajadlospisu = (String[])z.getArray();
            }
        }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("Query error. " +e);
        }
    catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.err.println("Element not found." +e);
        }

    return nazwajadlospisu;
    }
```

Any hints on how to implement this?

Comment: you miss a return in the end of your method

Comment: and your compiler should have told you that.

Comment: Avoid using underscores and capitalized starting-letters in local-scope variable names. See: _[Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)_

Comment: Are you sure a simple String array is the correct data structure you need and not at least a 2-dimensional array to store rows and columns? Because currently in your code your `T_NazwaJadlospisu` String array would only contain the last row of your select statement (Because you keep overriding it in the loop)

Comment: `return T_NazwaJadlospisu;` should show errors because `T_NazwaJadlospisu` is defined in while block and not accessible outside the `while` block

Comment: If you're getting a NullPointerException, you should figure out why, and fix it, instead of just catching it and letting everything carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that code that you need?

```
 public static String[] listJadlospis() {
        try {
            state = con.createStatement();
            result = state.executeQuery("SELECT NazwaJadlospisu FROM Jadlospis GROUP BY NazwaJadlospisu");

            List<String> nazwaJadlospisu= new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] T_NazwaJadlospisu = null;
            while (result.next()) {
                nazwaJadlospisu.add(result.getString(1))

                // String T_NazwaJadlospisu =
                // result.getString("NazwaJadlospisu");
                // System.out.println("Jadłospis: " + T_NazwaJadlospisu);
            }
            T_NazwaJadlospisu = new String[nazwaJadlospisu.size()];
            T_NazwaJadlospisu = nazwaJadlospisu.toArray(T_NazwaJadlospisu );
            return T_NazwaJadlospisu;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Query error.");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.err.println("Element not found.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, I have adopted your way and It looks I got rid of last error message. I need to check what has been returned from the method. It looks this is more then less what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this. You have to declare the array type which should be returned. This variable `String[] T_NazwaJadlospisu` has to be declared. Besides you have to return the array outside of try catch block. I provide an example here.

```java
public <ReturnType> functionName() {
    <ReturnType> <someName>;

    <try-catch>

    return <someName>;
}
```

The modified code is given below.

```java
public static String[] listJadlospis() {
    String[] T_NazwaJadlospisu = null; // DECLARE
    try {
        state = con.createStatement();
        result = state.executeQuery("SELECT NazwaJadlospisu FROM Jadlospis GROUP BY NazwaJadlospisu");
        while (result.next()) {
            Array z = result.getArray("NazwaJadlospisu");
            T_NazwaJadlospisu = (String[]) z.getArray(); // ASSIGN

            //String T_NazwaJadlospisu =
            //result.getString("NazwaJadlospisu");
            //System.out.println("Jadłospis: " + T_NazwaJadlospisu);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Query error.");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.err.println("Element not found.");
    }
    return T_NazwaJadlospisu; // RETURN
}
```

Comment: also I would suggest to throw the exception instead of print it

Comment: Could you at least explain what you did?

Comment: I updated the code to indicate the edits via upper-case comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `T_NazwaJadlospisu` is declared inside the while block. So it's scope is limited to that block only.

So there can be two solutions to that problem:

1) return it from the while loop. This this will return the first occurrence from the loop.

2) Declare it outside the loop and return it after the loop. And this will return the last occurrence from the loop.

So depending on your business scenario, you can use the solution accordingly.

**Returning First Occurrence:**

```
public static String[] listJadlospis() {

    try {
        state = con.createStatement();
        result = state.executeQuery("SELECT NazwaJadlospisu FROM Jadlospis GROUP BY NazwaJadlospisu");
        while (result.next()) {
            Array z = result.getArray("NazwaJadlospisu");
            String[] T_NazwaJadlospisu = (String[]) z.getArray();

            // String T_NazwaJadlospisu =
            // result.getString("NazwaJadlospisu");
            // System.out.println("Jadłospis: " + T_NazwaJadlospisu);
            return T_NazwaJadlospisu;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Query error.");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.err.println("Element not found.");
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Returning last occurrence:**

```
public static String[] listJadlospis() {

        try {
            state = con.createStatement();
            result = state.executeQuery("SELECT NazwaJadlospisu FROM Jadlospis GROUP BY NazwaJadlospisu");
            String[] T_NazwaJadlospisu = null;
            while (result.next()) {
                Array z = result.getArray("NazwaJadlospisu");
                T_NazwaJadlospisu = (String[]) z.getArray();

                // String T_NazwaJadlospisu =
                // result.getString("NazwaJadlospisu");
                // System.out.println("Jadłospis: " + T_NazwaJadlospisu);
            }
            return T_NazwaJadlospisu;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Query error.");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.err.println("Element not found.");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Few other observations:

1) Variables names are not as per Java standards.

2) Exception handling should do something meaningful rather than only printing it.